# I am getting an error in dreamweaver

Tags: asp.net

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Why am i getting this error in while browsing a page from dreamweaver? Here is my source code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">; <html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">; <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <title>Untitled Document</title> </head> <body> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Show us what line 1 looks like and maybe we could answer your question...

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Khatwani - in the future, edit your question and add detail there. Comments may end up being not read and as you can see code does not format well in them.

Answer (score 1):

You have semicolons after your `DOCTYPE` and your `<html />` open tag. Those seem likely to cause problems.

Otherwise, it seems likely DreamWeaver is not recognizing the `<%@ Page ... %>` tag. Does your filename end in `.aspx`? Does DreamWeaver even have ASP.NET support?

Comment: dreamweaver does have asp.net support.

Comment: ... and does your filename end in `.aspx`?

Comment: Is it running on a local web server? Maybe DreamWeaver is just trying to open the page locally, which would cause this problem.

Comment: Page displays fine when I view page with Visual studio. But when I view via macromedia I get the error